# Variation partitioning in vegan. Do variables need to be centered?

Tags: r, multivariate-analysis, vegan

I would like to carry out variation partitioning to see how landscape variables and local variables contribute to variation in species richness.  Do I need to centre my data prior to analysis?  Furthermore, my local variables are largely dummy coded factors (0|1) how do I approach this?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to centre the variables for `varpart()` (either the response or the predictors). If you have your variables coded as factors and not dummy variables, then **vegan** will create the correct contrasts for you.

So for a variable `colour` with three levels `red`, `green`, and `blue`, you'd have this as a single factor variable in R with those levels:

```
levs <- c("red", "green", "blue")
env <- data.frame(colour = factor(sample(levs, 100, replace = TRUE).
                                  levels = levs))
```

rather than three hand-coded dummy variables

```
env <- data.frame(colourRed = ...., colourGreen = ...., colourBlue =, ....)
```